# Got stuck at resoving an induction

Tags: algorithms

I encounter a problem numbered 9 in the homework exercise area of the book 《concrete mathmatics》, chapter 1. It is described as below:
  [image]

Now I've resolved the a and b but getting stuck in c. The answer is given like this:
  [image]

I know how to induce P(4) from P(2), but don't know how to induce P(3) from P(4) yet.
  Can anyone explain the way to me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific example of proving the statement for $n=5$, we can use part (a):
$$P(2) \overset{b}{\longrightarrow} P(4)  \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} P(3)  \overset{b}{\longrightarrow} P(6) \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} P(5)$$

In general, you can go up to a power of two and then down to the number. Using an appropriate choice for the power of two, you can get to any $n$, for example:

$$P(2) \overset{b}{\longrightarrow} P(4)  \overset{b}{\longrightarrow} P(8)  \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} P(7) \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} P(6) \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} P(5)$$

Comment: Thank you very much.I got it.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric Stucky's answer is correct. But I will try to clarify a bit more:

In part (a), you have already proved P(n) implied P(n-1) when n>1. So, for part (c), you can use part(a) to similarly say, P(4) implies P(3) when n=4.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Really appreciate it.